# Magento url rewrite re-indexing very slow

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

A client has a few hundred thousand products in Magento. Whenever client imports new products in (a few hundred each day), Magento needs to re-do the rewriting indexing. This is taking a long long time.  Is there any way to speed this up, or just have it process only the newly imported items rather than re-doing the entire catalog?

Comment: Is there a way to re-index only the newly imported items rather than the entire catalog?  That would be much better I think.  Old products never change anyways.

Comment: What are your server specs? Magento version and how many products total? You can use the shell/indexer.php file via CLI to facilitate specific index rebuilding if needed.  You may also want to read over Magento's Whitepaper: http://www.magentocommerce.com/whitepaper/

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to look at running a slave web server that talks to the same database. The slave server can do the reindexing (running with apache on 99% CPU) and write the modest amount of updates to the live server, not placing any load on it, maybe 2-3% CPU on mysql calls. In this way you get no performance problems on the frontend server.
Look at the /app/etc/local.xml file for the mysql connection and open up 3306 port on the live server. Then setup a development server to do the 'heavy reindexing'.